# Yii 2 multitranslation

Tags: php, yii

How to enable multitranslation in yii 2 basic framework? I have tried, but it is not working. I get no error, but translation is not showing. Code:

```
public function actionLang(){
    $lang = \Yii::$app->request->get('lang');
    if($lang && in_array($lang,['en-US','ar-SA'])){
        $cookie = new Cookie();
        $cookie->name = '_lang';
        $cookie->value = $lang;
        $cookie->expire = time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 180;
        \Yii::$app->response->cookies->add($cookie);
    }

    $this->redirect(['index']);
}
```

I'm using this function in SiteController.

Comment: Next time you post an answer, please read over it again. Check your grammar and spelling and also if your formatting worked (there is a preview function). Your code block didn't work properly.  If your answer is hard to read, you won't get any answers.

Answer (score 0):

Internationalization in Yii is not a one-action job. Here's the documentation on how to make your website multilingual:

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/tutorial-i18n.md

If docs are unclear, here is a tutorial:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/programming-with-yii2-localization-with-i18n--cms-23140

If you have gone through all the steps and merely wish to set the current language, you can use:

```
\Yii::$app->language = 'xxx';
```

where *xxx* is a language code in accordance with ISO 639-2.

Here are the mentioned standard's entries:

http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php

Answer (score 0):

First of all, from what I have gathered, you are trying to identify a language requested from the current request by doing `$lang = \Yii::$app->request->get('lang');` and then set it in the cookie. In my opinion, this should be used as a "helper", meaning, it is useful to know the language preference of the returning client, but you still have to manage languages via URL, i.e. `http://yoursite.com/en` or `http://yoursite.com/de` should serve different languages.

Now, there are actually very good plugins out there for multilingual URL management, such as `yii2-localeurls` , which you can find [here](https://github.com/codemix/yii2-localeurls). I use it in production in multiple projects and highly recommend it.

To actually manage translations, you have to have a folder in the root of your project (if you are using advance template, you should have it inside `frontend`/`backend`/`console` ) to store the actual block translations, call it `messages` .

Now, under `@app/messages` create folders for each non-default language, for example `@app/messages/de` for German translations.

If you go your config in `@app/config/main.php`, look for `i18n` key inside the `components` array. If you can't find such a key, simply put the following into the `components` array:

```
'i18n' => [
        'translations' => [
            'app*' => [
                'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                'basePath' => '@app/messages',
                'sourceLanguage' => 'en',
                'fileMap' => [
                    'app' => 'app.php',
                    'app/error' => 'error.php',
                ],

            ],
            '*' => [
                'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
            ]
        ],
    ],
```

Now, you will need to create a translation file inside the relevant directory. In the above configuration, we declared that the default language used is `en`, that means that all original messages would be in English. Go to `@app/messages/de` and create a translations file inside that directory. You can call it whatever you like, but for this example, call it `site.php`.

In this `site.php` put the following:

```
return [
    'Translate this!' => 'Your relevant translation here in whichever language',
    'Translate this also!!!' => 'Stuff...'
];
```

If all done correctly, when you access your page via `http://yousite.com/de`, when using `Yii::t('site', 'Translate this!')` you should be getting 'Your relevant translation here in whichever language' instead.

The beauty of Yii 2 is that it is extremely well documented. Visit the official documentation if you are stuck, it really explains everything quite well.